# SQL Server: update + count for each columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update my database. My `USER` table has a column `NbFollower` that should hold the number of people who follow this user.

So I need to count that number from another table `FOLLOWING_USER`.

The `USER.UserID = 1` appears 4 times in `FOLLOWING_USER`. That means he has 4 followers.

How can I use the function UPDATE and a COUNT at the same time, for each people ?

```
UPDATE [USER]
SET NbFollower = (SELECT count(User)
                  FROM FOLLOWING_USER FU
                  INNER JOIN [USER] U ON FU.[User] = U.UserID)
```

This returns "13" for ALL my users (13 is the total number of rows in `FOLLOWING_USER`)

So I need something like this, but automatised for all my users:

```
SELECT COUNT([User]) 
FROM FOLLOWING_USER 
WHERE [User] = 1
```

**EDIT**: here my table `USER`

```
CREATE TABLE [USER]
(
    UserID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    URL varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Age int NOT NULL,
    Gender char(1) NOT NULL,
    Location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(200) NULL,
    NbFollower int NULL DEFAULT 0,
    Rating int NULL DEFAULT 0
);

ALTER TABLE [USER]
    ADD ShareoutwardzID INT 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SHAREOUTWARDZ(ShareoutwardzID),
        CONSTRAINT Age CHECK (Age>=18);

INSERT INTO [USER] (Name, URL, Password, Email, Age, Gender, Location, Description, Rating)
VALUES
('lily', '/NAME', 'azertyuop123', 'lily@hotmail.com', 21, 'F', 'USA', NULL, 4);
```

Here my table `FOLLOWING_USER`:

```
CREATE TABLE FOLLOWING_USER
(
    [User] int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [USER](UserID),
    Follower int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FOLLOWER(UserID),
);

INSERT INTO FOLLOWING_USER([User], Follower)
VALUES (1, 9), (2, 9), (4, 9), (6, 9);
```

Comment: [USER] indicates that you are using sql server not mysql, please check your tags please

Comment: Also can you provide a create table and some data, it is quote unclear how the tabkes are related

Comment: Edited my post, ty for your reply.

Comment: Its normally a dangerous idea keeping counts on records like that. They will almost always be wrong for one reason or another. So if you know how to get the count, just create a view with that query in. Then your counts will always be accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there you can user the [user].user_id to xount only the correct number.

And you have to use COUNT(*)

> ```
> CREATE tABLE SHAREOUTWARDZ (ShareoutwardzID int PRIMARY KEY)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [USER]
> (
>     UserID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
>     URL varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>     Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
>     Password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>     Email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>     Age int NOT NULL,
>     Gender char(1) NOT NULL,
>     Location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>     Description varchar(200) NULL,
>     NbFollower int NULL DEFAULT 0,
>     Rating int NULL DEFAULT 0
> );
> ALTER TABLE [USER]
>     ADD ShareoutwardzID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SHAREOUTWARDZ(ShareoutwardzID),
>     CONSTRAINT Age CHECK (Age>=18);
> INSERT INTO [USER](Name, URL, Password, Email, Age, Gender, Location, Description, Rating)
> VALUES
> ('lily', '/NAME', 'azertyuop123', 'lily@hotmail.com', 21, 'F', 'USA', NULL, 4),
> ('MArk', '/NAME', 'azertyuop123', 'mark@hotmail.com', 21, 'M', 'USA', NULL, 4),
> ('Mary', '/NAME', 'azertyuop123', 'Mary@hotmail.com', 21, 'F', 'USA', NULL, 4),
> ('David', '/NAME', 'azertyuop123', 'david@hotmail.com', 21, 'M', 'USA', NULL, 4)
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE FOLLOWER(UserID int PRIMARY KEY);
> INSERT FOLLOWER VALUES (9)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE FOLLOWING_USER
> (
>     [User] int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [USER](UserID),
>     Follower int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FOLLOWER(UserID),
> );
> INSERT INTO FOLLOWING_USER([User], Follower)
> VALUES
> (1, 9),
> (2, 9),
> (2, 9),
> (3, 9);
> GO
> ```

> ```
>     UPDATE [USER]
> SET NbFollower = (SELECT count(*)
>                   FROM FOLLOWING_USER FU
>                   
>                   WHERE FU.[User] = [USER].UserID)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM [USER]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> UserID | URL   | Name  | Password     | Email             | Age | Gender | Location | Description | NbFollower | Rating | ShareoutwardzID
> -----: | :---- | :---- | :----------- | :---------------- | --: | :----- | :------- | :---------- | ---------: | -----: | --------------:
>      1 | /NAME | lily  | azertyuop123 | lily@hotmail.com  |  21 | F      | USA      | null        |          1 |      4 |            null
>      2 | /NAME | MArk  | azertyuop123 | mark@hotmail.com  |  21 | M      | USA      | null        |          2 |      4 |            null
>      3 | /NAME | Mary  | azertyuop123 | Mary@hotmail.com  |  21 | F      | USA      | null        |          1 |      4 |            null
>      4 | /NAME | David | azertyuop123 | david@hotmail.com |  21 | M      | USA      | null        |          0 |      4 |            null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88f906e8e52b59307ffbed535c60fffa)*

Comment: You the best, thank for all! Have a good day :) Dont know why i wanted to use a JOIN but i was not so far as the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [USER]
SET NbFollower = UserCount.TotalCount
                 FROM [USER]
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(User) TotalCount, User 
                             FROM [Following_User] GROUP BY User) As UserCount
                 ON UserCount.User = [USER].UserId
```